# How to modify/convert raw stream data during copy to another stream?

Tags: c#, stream, .net-4.5, converters

I have any `System.IO.Stream` with input data and another one to write output to. What's a good way to copy stream contents while beeing able to detect certain keywords and modifying/removing data from the stream?

Do I have to use `.Read` and `.Write` and a buffer and deal with buffer boundaries myself (like only a part of a keyword at the end of the buffer)? Of course that's not too hard, but I hope for something more fashionable, like inheriting some ready-made stream converter class.

For example, since it's for MS Exchange anyway, I tried to inherit `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.TextConverters.TextConverter`, but it looks like this is not possible?

I know, encoding could be another issue, but let's treat it as raw bytes for this question.